# Is it possible to find the Wikipedia ID by property, e.g. Grid ID

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikidata

Wikidata stores the Grid ID of educational institutions in property 2427 (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2427). Is it possible to retrieve the Wikipedia ID for a given Grid ID.

Example: I know the value "grid.1012.2" as Grid ID. 
I would like to get Q1517021 back!

I tried

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&format=json&property=P2427&claim=grid.1012.2
```

without success...

Comment: i don't think you can do this using api.php. You can do it with SPARQL. You'll need to specify the edu institution ID (Q id) and the Wikipedia ID property.

Comment: @JayGray, it is not possible to get Wikipedia API using pure SPARQL on WDQS. Only using [MWAPI](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the search API with the `haswbstatement` keyword ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#haswbstatement)): [`action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=haswbstatement%3AP2427%3Dgrid.1012.2`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=haswbstatement%3AP2427%3Dgrid.1012.2)

Although as suggested by others using [SPARQL](https://query.wikidata.org/) might be easier for these kinds of things.